# launchUrl with external Google/Apple Maps, Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies, url-launcher

Since `launch` is deprecated and it shouldn't be used, I tried using `launchUrl` instead. It use to open the google maps or apple maps, but now it just opens the web view inside the app and it is often not displaying the right information on the map. I have a starting location and an ending location, when I press the button, it use to open the maps and shows the precise location, but after parsing the string and changing to `launchUrl` it doesn't work as intended..
Old working method for openMapDirections:

```
static Future<void> openMapDirections(String? startLatitude,
      String? startLongitude, String? endLatitude, String? endLongitude) async {
    String googleUrl =
        'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=$startLatitude,$startLongitude&destination=$endLatitude,$endLongitude&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate';
    if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
      await launch(googleUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the map.';
    }
  }
```

New method that doesn't work and is not opening the external map app:

```
static Future<void> openMapDirections(String? startLatitude,
      String? startLongitude, String? endLatitude, String? endLongitude) async {
    String googleUrl =
        'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=$startLatitude,$startLongitude&destination=$endLatitude,$endLongitude&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate';
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(googleUrl))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(googleUrl));
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the map.';
    }
  }
```

Even with parsing the string it doesn't work. I have read the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) docs, and done the same thing but it doesn't work. I have previously added the

```
<intent>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
```

inside the android manifest. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the launch method, specify the launchMode property

```
launch(url, launchMode: 
LaunchMode.externalApplication
 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `externalApplication` or `externalNonBrowserApplication` as value for [LaunchMode](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher_string/LaunchMode.html). For example

```
Future<void> _launchUniversalLink(Uri url) async {
    final bool nativeAppLaunchSucceeded = await launchUrl(
      url,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
    );
    if (!nativeAppLaunchSucceeded) {
      await launchUrl(
        url,
        mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
      );
    }
  }
```